# System.out.println: Why are non printable characters only displayed before a printable one but not after that?

Tags: java

If we take this example:

`System.out.println(new String(new byte[]{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,112,0,0,0}));`

the console will show some squares(the not displayable characters) and then the character 'p'(112). Why the next three "square" are not displayed?

Comment: Can't reproduce, has probably smthg to do with your console.

Comment: This is highly dependent on many factors, including your operating system, your preferred locale, display settings in your terminals, fonts, etc. No one can answer this without a lot more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters are NUL, SOH, and STX.   I imagine that your font maps NUL to 'nothing'.  This is likely not true for SOH and STX.

In my attempt to reproduce this locally (on a Raspberry Pi-zero system running Raspbian, connected from Windows 10 via putty) I see only the 'p' on output to the console.  If I redirect the output to a file that I then examine in a suitable editor, I see all NUL, SOH, STX present.

In other words, what you see is highly dependent on almost everything else except Java.

(Your Java locale could have an effect, but I am assuming the more likely case that byte values 0 to 31 map directly into equivalent char values)